# Want a big table in top-center of a two-column article page

Tags: xetex, floats, positioning, two-column

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} %%Should compile with XeLatex
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Delicious SmallCaps]{Delicious-Roman} %%Want to use this FONT

\usepackage{multicol}

\title{\textsc{My Title}}
\author{
    Author Details }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
...

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Ename & \underline{Eid} & Salary & Dno & Supervisor\_eid \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption {\textbf{EMP} Database Schema}
\end{table}

...

\end{document}
```

The {XeLatex} Compilation fails when I use `table*` environment. What is the solution?

Error:
    `[4]
    ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
    \@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                          \color@endbox 
    l.317 \end{table*}`

Comment: I was about to suggest to use the multicol package, but you're already loading that one - without using it. Currently, you're relying on twocolumn in the documentclass; delete that and then use \begin{multicols}{2} blocks around your text to achieve the same result. However, I'm not sure whether that will help with your actual problem. (Separate multicols environments around every table will probably mess up the layout.)

Comment: Did you include the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array), since you're using `\extrarowheight`?

Comment: When I include the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array), remove all the font-specific components (since I don't have `Delicious-Roman`) and use `table*`, I have no problem under `xelatex`. Remember that `table*` does *not* have any mandatory width arguments like `tabular*` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\usepackage{multicol,array}` I have no problem with your example. Current TeXLive 2011

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I found out the culprit line :-X... I was using a VERY LARGE TEX file in which I always include many packages by default. In this particular case, `subfigure` package was causing anonymous behaviour. After uncommenting it, it started to work like a jiffy :)..